# Стоит ли делать изометрическую игру используя для графики css3?

Tags: javascript, css3, canvas, разработка-игр

Хотел сделать для себя и возможно для знакомых изометрическую стратегию на подобии Травиан, но нету желания сейчас изучать canvas, по этому думаю использовать для графической части CSS3.

Есть несколько примеров, которые можно использовать для дальнейшего развития, такие как:

https://codepen.io/joshnh/pen/IchEz

```
.cube,
.cube:after,
.cube:before {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .25em hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    content: '';
    float: left;
    height: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 3em;
}
/* Top */
.cube {
    background-color: #f66;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(3em);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: .25s;
}
/* Left */
.cube:after {
    background-color: #e55;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(3em);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
/* Right */
.cube:before {
    background-color: #d44;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(3em);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Jordan/pen/snjJi

```
#plane div{
  float:left;
  background:#f6f6f6;
  transform-origin: 97% 97%;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow:.125em .125em .5em rgba(0,0,0,.09);
}

.tall{
  background:white !important;
  transform: translateZ(1em);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.tall:before, .tall:after{
  content:"";
  background:darkcyan;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
.tall:before{
  transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateY(1em);
  box-shadow:inset 0em -.125em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.tall:after{
  transform:rotateY(90deg) translateX(1em);
  box-shadow:inset -.125em 0em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

Я больше ссылаюсь к первому варианту реализации, но есть вопрос, не будет ли это большой нагрузкой на браузер и оперативную память? Стоит ли делать таким способом? Какие подводные камни мне могут встретиться?

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю о чем Вы говорите, не о самой игре не об её механике, но я знаю одно - некоторые игры реально проще сделать на `html` + `css`, как бы оно смешно не звучало. Я лично создавал игры и на `flash` и на `canvas` и на `css` и могу заверить, что игры где нет персонажей, как пазлы, текстовые квесты, возможно примитивные головоломки, настольные игры лучше и быстрее и дешевле сделать на `html` + `css`.

Вы должны понимать что в играх главное логика, а логика это `javascript` и ему без разницы с чем работать. А учитывая то, что настольные приложения или мобильные заворачиваются в `chromium` позволяет использовать `css` на полную - переменные, функции и прочие.

Даже если есть какие-то накладные эффекты с ограниченной-небольшой областью действия, то их лучше делать на `canvas`, а дальше работать с ним как с `html` элементом.

Comment: Хороший ответ, но пожалуйста, не нужно оборачивать названия технологий в тэги `предназначенные для выделения кода`

Comment: @Kromster а разве так не положено? Вроде даже модераторы всегда выделяют не выделенные ключевые слова. Может они это по другому делают?

Comment: Видимо они не читали http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютно не стоит. Будет чертовски, просто ужастно сложно рулить всем этим через js, и верстать всё так чтобы работало не только в браузере. Демо которое вы показали как пример - всего лишь демо, для разработки игр css не предназначен от слова совсем. Учите canvas и WebGL, на одном CSS вы точно далеко не уедете.